# How to remove unwanted branch from a ContourPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have the following Mathematica code:

```
$Assumptions = {r ∈ Reals, r >= 0, rh ∈ Reals, rh > 0};
qe = rh  ϕe;
M[rh_, qm_, ϕe_] := qe^2/(2 rh) + qm^2/(2 rh) + rh/2 + rh^3/(2 l^2)
f[r_, rh_, qm_, ϕe_] := 1 + r^2/l^2 - (2 M[rh, qm, ϕe])/r + (qe^2 + qm^2)/r^2
T[rh_, qm_, ϕe_] := 1/(4 π rh^3) (-ϕe^2 rh^2 + (3 rh^4)/l^2 + rh^2 - qm^2)

Veff[r_] = f[r, rh, qm, ϕe] (L^2/r^2 + 1);

l = 1; L = 20; ϕe = 0.6; qm = 0.06;

rhmin = SolveValues[T[rh, qm, ϕe] == 0, rh, Reals][[1]]

belt = ContourPlot3D[Veff'[r] == 0, {rh, rhmin, 1}, {r, rh, 5}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

which gives me the following plot:

[image: contour]

Which has all the branches of the solution. I know that I can manually remove one branch of the solution, like this:

```
rsol[rh_] = SolveValues[Simplify[Veff'[r] == 0], r][[2 ;; 3]]

Plot[rsol[rh], {rh, rhmin, 1}]
```

[image: plot]

But how to do it directly in the contour plot itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extracted the upper limit from condition of `sol` by `sol[[1, 2, 5]]`.

```
sol = SolveValues[Simplify[Veff'[r] == 0], r, Reals][[2 ;; 3]] // 
   Quiet;

ContourPlot3D[
 Evaluate@{r == sol[[1, 1]], r == sol[[2, 1]]}, {rh, rhmin, 
  sol[[1, 2, 5]]}, {r, rh, 5}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried `Plot3D` instead of `ContourPlot3D` and it works:

```
sol[rh_,z_] := SolveValues[Simplify[Veff'[r] == 0], r, Reals][[2 ;; 3]]

belt = Plot3D[sol[rh,z], {rh, rhmin, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image: plot3d]

I hope someone can answer how to directly do it in the `ContourPlot3D` itself.